# Override typing for strict null check

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I want to switch to use strict null checks on my typescript 2.0 project, but I'm having some difficulties with the typings of a dependency of one of my dependencies (dependency grandparent if you'd like).

In more detail, I have dependencies `B` and `C` which both depends on `A`. All of these are transpiled TS projects, with code and typings available in a `lib` folder, and they have not yet switched to strict null checks.

The relevant typings in `A` are like follows:

```
interface IInterface {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Which are used in both `B` and `C` as follows:

```
import { IInterface } from 'A/lib/iinterface';

interface IExtended extends IInterface {
  myOptionalProperty?: string
}
```

With strict null checks, this gives the following compilation error:

```
node_modules/B/lib/extended.d.ts(4,3): error TS2411: Property 'myOptionalProperty' of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string'
node_modules/C/lib/extended.d.ts(4,3): error TS2411: Property 'myOptionalProperty' of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string'
```

The question is then twofold:

1. To comply with strict checks, the typing in A needs to be changed to:

   `interface IInterface {
     [key: string]: string | undefined;
   }`

   I am not sure if it is possible to override such a type, as this is not simply an extension of existing types. If possible, how is it done?
2. If possible, how should it be included such that the typings in `B` and `C` are checked against my overridden typing, and not what is in their local `node_modules` directory?

Comment: The ideal solution is of course to have project `A` add these typings themselves, and I already have a PR to that effect, but there will be quite some time before this is accepted and propagated down to projects `B` and `C`, so I'm looking for a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to just tell the compiler to skip the checks for the libs you are using.
The [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) now have the `skipDefaultLibCheck`:

> Don’t check a user-defined default library (*.d.ts) file’s validity.

And `skipLibCheck`:

> Don’t check a the default library (lib.d.ts) file’s validity.

So if you compile using that option set to `true` then you shouldn't get errors for the libs you are using.

There's more about it in the [what's new for typescript 2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new---skiplibcheck):

> TypeScript 2.0 adds a new --skipLibCheck compiler option that causes
>   type checking of declaration files (files with extension .d.ts) to be
>   skipped. When a program includes large declaration files, the compiler
>   spends a lot of time type checking declarations that are already known
>   to not contain errors, and compile times may be significantly
>   shortened by skipping declaration file type checks.

Comment: Thanks! I had encountered this flag when searching for a solution, but had misinterpreted what it did. Solves problem and speeds up build time as well :)